# Get Daylight Savings in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, dst

I need to build a function that returns "1" if it's summer time, or "0" for winter.

Just wanted to ask for an algorithm for it to start with or how to start will be helpful.

Comment: One possible option is a combination of `time()` and `localtime()` from `<ctime>`.  That works in C and should in C++ too.  Whether it's a good option is another matter, but it isn't trivial to do otherwise.  That will report on the status of winter vs summer time for the given time, more or less.

Comment: An algorithm that *mostly* works worldwide is: 1) Get offsets for Jan 1st and July 1st.  If they are the same, DST is not applicable, return `0`.  2) Get the *current* offset.  3) If the current offset equals the *smaller* of the two offsets, then *standard time* is in effect, return `0`, else DST is in effect so return `1`.  This holds true except when offsets change for non-DST reasons (such as base-offset changes).

Answer (score 0):

For windows.

You can use `_SYSTEMTIME` to get the current month/date (local or systemtime). Then if it's fall in a range for daylight savings you can return yes, you have daylight savings, else return no. (i.e. make your own simple function)

Example usage of `_SYSTEMTIME` and docs [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: (a) You should probably explicitly mention that this is for Windows, and (b) I'm not clear how you get whether daylight saving time is in effect or not from the information it returns.  Maybe you have an '…and then magic happens…' step in "if it falls in a range for daylight savings"; how do you know whether daylight savings is in effect or not?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Marked. And I assume the programmer would know when day light savings time occurs, so from what month/day to other month/day, and they simply check if the date they currently get is within that range.

Comment: Do you know when the change occurs — in Morrocco, Georgia (the country, not the US state), China, Japan, Australia, Chile, Argentina?  Do you know how often the rules change in some country each year?  There's a mailing list for that — and the current release for this year is a modest version '2015f', I believe, but it got to release '2009s', so that was 19 releases in that year.  And often a release bundles changes for several countries.  Expecting the programmer to 'know' is not a winning strategy.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Point taken.

Comment: See https://www.iana.org/time-zones: I had problems getting 2015g but that's supposed to be the current release.  _[…Hmmm; a retry worked; not sure what happened…]_  The chances are that'll be the last release in 2015, but that's not guaranteed until 2016-01-01.